# android - Moto G mobile not showing up in the devices list in Android studio for windows 8 x64bit

Tags: android

Currently trying to use windows 8 x64 bit android studio to create apps. The Moto G worked fine when it was connected to a mac, but now that I've switched to a windows computer, it connects and the computer recognizes it but only for photos. I've turned on the USB debugging option in "developer options" on the phone already and it does say "USB debugging connected" when I connect it, but it just doesn't show up on the devices list when I try running the code on android studio.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Settings -> About phone -> Build Number (tap this one 7 times).
Install MOTO G Drivers 
(https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_detail/a_id/97326/p/30,6720,9050)
Now, connect your phone as Camera (PTP). It worked for me on Windows 8.
Hope it works! :)

Comment: The link is showing Not available. Please update it

Answer (score 5):

To solve this problem I had to install the Motorola Device Manager:

[Download it here](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDg5NTgzNjMwL3NpZC9mVTk4ajJ0M1JtTnFsbnpGQ0ZmMjRfN3VYOWtqZkpaTnJDQ3pGMml2QUVqRHlZVVMzRzdicDQ0SDUyNUVWVUZrbXM2OHVIeU5iS2o4Z29ZbW1YU3licVpYQlZlSmh4TmpXUjNFYnVmbjFJRmFmcWdBRGpXc3lCS0ElMjElMjE%3D)

Afer installing the Motorola Device Manager, Motorola devices were recognized by Android Studio in my Windows 8.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem then I reinstalled my Device Driver, Now its working,
Just Install the Drivers for your Device Properly [https://mobilesupport.lenovo.com/us/en/solution/MS88481]