# moto g play not recognized in adb device list after upgrade

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, adb

Moto g play was working fine until i upgraded my android from 6.0 to 6.1.0(marshmellow), also when i connect i don't find the connection type notification in the notification bar(it was earlier showing). i tried connecting nexus with version 6.1.0 to my windows - this picked up, but moto g play stopped to appear in windows and mac. i tried all possible suggestion like changing USB type from charging to MTP and to PTP no use. Any help at all is greatfull.

Links i tried before posting this [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217792/android-moto-g-mobile-doesnt-show-in-the-devices-list-of-eclipse) [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374012/android-moto-g-mobile-not-showing-up-in-the-devices-list-in-android-studio-for)

Comment: I had similar issue with my redmi note 4, when i tried rooting. Are you rooted or on custom rom?

Comment: @AswinPAshok: it is not rooted. still in factory

Comment: Official update? You sure usb debugging is enabled?

Comment: @AswinPAshok: Yes my usb debugging is enabled